# В каком порядке выполняются фикстуры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Использую pytest для тестирования. Использую фикстуры в качестве тестовых пре- и посткондишенов. Но разные тесты требуют разный набор этих самых прекондишенов и для получения тестовых данных.

Обычный тест имеет вид:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('fixture1', 'fixture2')
def test_testname(some_fixture):
    pass
```

some_fixture - постоянно плавающая фикстура, которая для каждого теста разная. Это тестовые данные.
fixture1 и fixture2 - это фикстуры, которые, как раз-таки, приводят систему в необходимое состояние. На данный момент они друг от друга никак не зависят.
В это уравнение мне нужно впихнуть fixture3. При этом важно, чтобы она выполнялась ПЕРЕД fixture1.

Если фикстуры в usefixtures выполняются просто по порядку, то вопрос снимается как дурацкий. Если же нет, то как?

Comment: Попробуйте это почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660064/in-which-order-are-pytest-fixtures-executed

Comment: Мне кажется, что делать фикстуры зависимыми от порядка запуска это в принципе плохая идея

Comment: Если fixture1 зависит от fixture3, то выразите это явно - fixture3 должна быть параметром в fixture1. И создаваться она будет до инициализации fixture1.

Comment: Фиктуры друг от друга по прежнему никак не зависят. Просто мне важно, чтобы fixture3 выполнялась перед fixture1. Получается так, что 3я меняет один конфиг, а 1я запускает бинари. И важно, чтобы конфиг был изменён до запуска бинарей.

Comment: Как же не зависят, если нужно, чтобы одна отработала перед другой?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что сам код фикстур никак не пересекается. Пересекается непосредственно функционал, который они реализуют.